# sort and iterate over items in an array of array column in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In pyspark I have a data frame composed of two columns

Assume the details in the array of array are
timestamp, email, phone number, first name, last name, address, city, country, randomId

```
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| str1                    | array_of_str                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| random column data1     | [[‘2020-01-26 17:30:57.000 +0000’, ’’, ‘728-802-5766’, ‘’, ‘’, ‘7th street crossroads’, ‘seattle’, ‘’, ‘randomId104’], [‘2019-07-20 20:54:57.000 +0000’, ’abaudi0@patch.com’, ‘728-802-5766’, ‘Katuscha’, ‘’, ‘’, ‘’, ‘us’, ‘randomId225’], [‘2015-12-04 04:54:57.000 +0000’, ’abaudi0-temp@patch.com’, ‘728-802-5766’, ‘’, ‘Othen’, ‘7th street crossroads’, ‘seattle’, ‘’, ‘randomid306’]]|
| random column data2     | [[‘2021-01-30 17:30:04.000 +0000’, ’jallmann2@digg.com’, ‘313-984-9692’, ‘’, ‘’, ‘th street crossroads’, ‘New york’, ‘us’, ‘randomId563’], [‘2018-05-15 20:44:57.000 +0000’, ’cgodlee6@sphinn.com’, ‘’, ‘Marianne’, ‘Allmann’, ‘’, ‘’, ‘us’, ‘randomId884’]]                                                                                                                                |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I am expecting output data frame like below

```
+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| str1                    | array_of_str                                                                                                                                         |
+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| random column data1     | [‘2020-01-26 17:30:57.000 +0000’, ’abaudi0@patch.com’, ‘728-802-5766’, ‘Katuscha’, ‘Othen’, ‘7th street crossroads’, ‘seattle’, ‘us’, ‘randomid306’] |
| random column data2     | [‘2021-01-30 17:30:04.000 +0000’, ’jallmann2@digg.com’, ‘313-984-9692’, ‘Marianne’, ‘Allmann’, ‘111th Ave NE’, ‘New york’, ‘us’, ‘randomId884’]      |
+-------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- +
```

optional :- existing data in array of array might not be already sorted at decreasing timestamp order. How do I sort the array of array in decreasing timestamp order

Here I am planning to write a udf to pull latest non null (timestamp, email, phone number, first name, last name, address, city, country) data from array of array. In case of randomId, I will always pull the randomId associated with the oldest record in the system.

example:- for `random column data1` emailId i.e. `abaudi0@patch.com` is getting populated from second element in the array since the first one is having empty email id.
similar is the case with other columns.
In case of `randomid` `randomid306` for first record is the oldest entry so its populated in my output data frame.

In the udf

1. How do I sort the array of array elements in descending timestamp order? - kind of an optional step
2. How do i iterate over the array of array column in the data frame?

3)How to access individual items on the array in a udf?

like in the case of python we can iterate over list of list elements like

```
for item in items:
   print(item[0], item[1])
```

how can I achieve similar thing for array of array columns in pyspark?

can I do above steps in pyspark by not converting the data to pandas dataframe?

spark version 2.4.3
python 3.6.8

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in [sort_array](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.sort_array.html#pyspark.sql.functions.sort_array) for this, create a new column using this and extract the first element `(0)` using [getItem](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.getItem.html#pyspark.sql.Column.getItem)

## Built in sort_array

```
input_list = [('10',[
                  ['2020-01-26 17:30:57.000 +0000', '', '728-802-5766', '', '', '7th street crossroads', 'seattle', '', 'randomId104']
                , ['2019-07-20 20:54:57.000 +0000', 'abaudi0@patch.com', '728-802-5766', 'Katuscha', '', '', '', 'us', 'randomId225']
                , ['2015-12-04 04:54:57.000 +0000', 'abaudi0-temp@patch.com', '728-802-5766', '', 'Othen', '7th street crossroads', 'seattle', '', 'randomid306']
            ])
        ,('20',[
          ['2021-01-30 17:30:04.000 +0000', 'jallmann2@digg.com', '313-984-9692', '', '', 'th street crossroads', 'New york', 'us', 'randomId563']
        , ['2018-05-15 20:44:57.000 +0000', 'cgodlee6@sphinn.com', '', 'Marianne', 'Allmann', '', '', 'us', 'randomId884']
        ])
    ]

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(input_list,['id','array_str'])


sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('sorted_array_str'
                                 ,F.sort_array(F.col('array_str'),False).getItem(0))


sparkDF.select(['id','sorted_array_str']).show(truncate=False)
```

## UDF

```
# array_sort_udf, sorts on the timestamp , can be futher customized for giving precedence to multiple elements

array_sort_udf = F.udf(lambda x : sorted(x,key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True), ArrayType(StringType()))

sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('sorted_array_str'
                                 ,array_sort_udf(F.col('array_str')).getItem(0))

sparkDF.select(['id','sorted_array_str']).show(truncate=False)
```

## Output

```
+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |sorted_array_str                                                                                                      |
+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|10 |[2020-01-26 17:30:57.000 +0000, , 728-802-5766, , , 7th street crossroads, seattle, , randomId104]                    |
|20 |[2021-01-30 17:30:04.000 +0000, jallmann2@digg.com, 313-984-9692, , , th street crossroads, New york, us, randomId563]|
+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```